# how to compare whether an item is already added in an arraylist<hashmap<string,string>>?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, comparison

I am trying to do the following:

1. I am retrieving some `preferences` value from the server and setting it in `Toggle Button` in a `ListView`.
2. On selecting a particular preference and clicking a button I want the that item to be added to a arraylist.
   for eg:

item_id=1;
Category="Pizza"
Preferences on the Listview 1. Xtra Cheese 2. Xtra Salt.

On Selecting `Xtra Cheese` I want my item to be added to the arraylist i.e `cart`.
On selecting `Xtra Cheese` and `Xtra Salt` I want again my item to be added to `cart`.
That is I want the items with different prefernce combinations to be added to the `cart` only once.

I have done the following coding. Please tell me step by step what to do.

```
    add_list_to_cart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // String pref_name1="pref_name";
            int pre_arr_len = prefern_arr1.length;
            HashMap<String, String> cart_list = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String qty = quantity.getText().toString();
            // HashSet hs = new HashSet();
            cart_list.put("quantity", "" + qty);
            cart_list.put("item_id", "" + item_id_number);
            cart_list.put("Category", Itemname);
            cart_list.put("Details", Item_details);
            cart_list.put("Price", Item_price);
            cart_list.put("Currency", Item_currency);
            cart_list.put("images", images); 
            if(pre_arr_len!=0)
            {
            for (int i = 0; i < pre_arr_len; i++) {
                String temp = prefern_arr1[i];
                if (temp != null && temp.compareToIgnoreCase("empty") != 0) {
                    cart_list.put(temp, temp);
                    if(cart.size()!=0)
                    {
                        if (cart.get(i).containsKey("item_id"))
                        {
                            if (cart.get(i).containsValue(item_id_number))
                            {
                                cart.get(i).containsValue(temp);
                                String pref_id = getKeyByValue(cart.get(i), temp);
                                //compare if the same prefernce cobinations exist
                                //if(yes)
                                //{
                                    //don't add to cart
                                //}
                                //else
                                //{add to cart}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
               }
            }
                cart.add(cart_list);





       public <T, E> E getKeyByValue(Map<T, E> map, E value) {
            for (Entry<T, E> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                if (value.equals(entry.getValue())) {
                    // return entry.getKey();
                    return entry.getValue();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> test = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
boolean exists = false;
for (HashMap<String, String> hmap : test)
{
    if (hmap.get("item_id").equals("to_check_id"))
    {
        //exists
        exists = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (exists)
{
    //exists do something
}
```

**EDIT**

In your case

```
    boolean exists = false;
    for (HashMap<String, String> hmap : cart)
    {
        if (hmap.get("item_id").equals(cart_list.get("item_id"))
        {
            //exists
            exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!exists)
    {
        //does not exist
        //add to card
        card.add(cart_list);
    }
    else
    {
        //item already exists
    }
```